# Backslashes interpreted as control character in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, latex, tex

I've got **LaTex** code from server and have **no control** over it. I would like to print the LaTex code as it is using JavaScript, but it interprets as control characters on assigning to variable.

```
var str = '\[\frac{{{d^2}y}}{{d{x^2}}} - \,3\,\left( {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}} \right)\, + \,2y\, = \,0\]';
```

This interprets as follows

```
[rac{{{d^2}y}}{{d{x^2}}} - ,3,left( {rac{{dy}}{{dx}}} ight), + ,2y, = ,0]
```

And I want as follows:

```
\[\frac{{{d^2}y}}{{d{x^2}}} - \,3\,\left( {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}} \right)\, + \,2y\, = \,0\]
```

I tried varies RegExps, and result of

```
var index = str.indexOf("\\")
```

is **-1**

JavaScript removes control characters like \f, \r and so on and there are thousands of backslash notations in TeX.

Comment: How are you getting the code from the server? What is the server response type? If the server does not output the right escaped string, then you have to fix it on the server... If you have no control over it, I think you're screwed...

Comment: I've already said that its beyond my control that how I should get the LaTeX code, my role is to render it to graphics using JavaScript, and I stuck in this situation.

Comment: That's not what you were asked. In which way you get (without control) the LaTex code. How is loaded in str var?

Comment: It's a text/plain response from server, I get it from from Ajax request and assign it to the var. BTW its not important how I get it to assigned to a var. Please focus on the problem. That's why I'm on SOF!

Comment: This is only a representative presentation. I also get response in json format, still the string gets interpreted with escape characters and they simply been removed.

Comment: Ok, you got an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is loaded in str var?

Anyway, there is a work around (**[working here](http://jsfiddle.net/3U5vA/)**):

```
var c=',[]flr';
for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++)
 eval("str=str.replace(/\\"+c.charAt(i)+"/g,'\\\\"+c.charAt(i)+"');");
```

What we do is for any char in *c* evaluate the following code (replacing X with the char):

```
str=str.replace(/\X/g,'\\X');
```

Anyway, there is a work around (**[working here](http://jsfiddle.net/3U5vA/)**):

```
var c=',[]flr';
for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++)
 eval("str=str.replace(/\\"+c.charAt(i)+"/g,'\\\\"+c.charAt(i)+"');");
```

What we do is for any char in *c* evaluate the following code (replacing X with the char):

```
str=str.replace(/\X/g,'\\X');
```

---

Ok, that's an odd (and maybe dangerous) bug at the site which delivers the JSON. If it does not turns the \' to \', maybe it does not turns the ' to \'. So, anything after a ' or a " (depending on how the string is quoted) **will be executed** on any site that includes that (i.e. **your site**). Maybe as JSON is a little more secure.

Comment: How many characters should I assign to c? Here we know these are ,[]flr. Or we require to assign whole set of characters from ascii (7-bit); but these characters are unpredicted as there are lots of TeX escape sequences coming from TeX server. However the solution is quite acceptable and thanks for the solution, you saved my time!

Comment: Is there any other way to tell JS not to execute escape sequences quoted in single or double. Like in Perl, it doesn't execute the string when quoted in single. But we have not choice for JS!

Comment: You're wellcome. As far as I know there's no way to avoid execution of escape sequences. You could use a for(var i=32;i<127;i++) eval(...).